# Are hgrc files inside a mercurial repo tracked by the repo itself?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

We have an hgrc file that contains settings that should be global to all members of our development team.  When I make changes to my hgrc file I do not appear to be able to have these changes propagate to anybody else who clones a repo.

Is there a way to keep these configs global to any user of the repo?

Repo track thyself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$REPO/.hg/hgrc** is not tracked by Mercurial. This is by design for security reason.

You can commit template and create project policy that require setting several setting to **$REPO/.hg/hgrc** or add to build scripts helper target to deploy template to **$REPO/.hg**.

I recommend use precommit hooks on central server to ensue that all changes are **good**. Look to

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples
- http://hg.python.org/hooks/ -hooks from Python project.

Note that some files Mercurial treated as special, for example **$REPO/.hgignore** or **.hgeol** for EOL plug-in. These files you can commit, so they are easy sharing in dev team.